# Double postback due to select and change event

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, .net

I am not quite sure how to solve this issue. I have a textbox like control which makes use of .select and .change events. The text box provides values to select from as you are typing.

The problem I am having is that on selecting a value it posts back and does its stuff (correct) but then the minute you click away it posts back again because it fires the .change event.

I need the .change event to only fire when an item is changed (existing item and not a new item selected).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just cache the last value used to in the postback eg.

```
if ($("#mydiv").val() === lastpoststring)
{return ;}
// do postback..
var lastpoststring = $("#mydiv").val(); // this gets called every time a postback happens
```